# Regex keep all lines with delimiter (sublime)

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I'm having a file with lots of text but on some rows there are lines with just:

`sometext:someothertext`

What i want is to keep those lines.
I've written a regex but that does the exact opposite of what i want:

`[0-9a-zA-Z]+(:[0-9a-zA-Z]+)`

Also there are a few lines with have the delimiter in it. I don't need to keep those. A sample line would be:

> This is a very nice line saying stuff about **sometext:someothertext**

How would the regex look like to get just the lines containing `sometext:someothertext` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?![0-9a-zA-Z]+:[0-9a-zA-Z]+$).*$\R*
```

This expression will work [like this](https://regex101.com/r/lF8xZ7/1).

Replacement text is empty.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of line (the `m` multiline option is default in SublimeText)
- `(?![0-9a-zA-Z]+:[0-9a-zA-Z]+$)` - the line should not match the pattern: 1+ alphanumerics followed with a `:` and again 1 or more alphanumerics
- `.*$` - matches the whole (even empty) line
- `\R*` - and zero or more linebreaks.

If I have  the following text:

```
local06:local16
TEXT local76:local16
local06:local17
local06:local19

More TEXT local76:local678
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working as it should be! I didn't know about "Not matching"

Comment: That `(?!...)` construct is called a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). The `$` inside it tells the regex engine to check the *whole line*, else, it would only fail the match in case a line started with your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a negative example:

```
[^: \t]:[^: \t]
```

Match:

1. not colon, space or tab
2. colon
3. not colon, space or tab

You can add to the "not" character class(es) anything else you would like to exclude.

Here is a more positive example:

```
[0-9A-Za-z]:[0-9A-Za-z]
```

Use with grep, awk, or sed and the above will match the line for printing:

```
grep '[^: \t]:[^: \t]' foo.txt
awk '/[^: \t]:[^: \t]/' foo.txt
sed '/[^: \t]:[^: \t]/ p; d' foo.txt

grep '[0-9A-Za-z]:[0-9A-Za-z]' foo.txt
awk '/[0-9A-Za-z]:[0-9A-Za-z]/' foo.txt
sed '/[0-9A-Za-z]:[0-9A-Za-z]/ p; d' foo.txt
```

If you want to match the whole line... You can use `.*` before and after either regex.